# How can I make an array of files found in a folder? (SwiftUI)

Tags: arrays, swift

Tried looking this up from multiple places, but I can't wrap my head around this one.

I just want to make a variable with just an array list of the files/filenames. I've found code from other places but it just gives me nothing but a handful of errors (the code below gives an URL must be unwrapped error and nil errors.)

```
let happy_alt = FileManager().contentsOfDirectory(at: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Sounds/Happy_alt", withExtension: nil), includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: [])
```

I'm still fairly new to Swift, can someone help me understand what I'd need to either fix the current code, or is there a better way to make an array of files?

Comment: The important thing to understand is there may not be a URL for `Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Sounds/Happy_alt", withExtension: nil)` because maybe the bundle doesn't have such a resource. You can't know for sure until you try it at runtime. So it has to be a value of type `URL?` and not a `URL`. Your code must handle both cases.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
do {
    guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Sounds/Happy_alt", withExtension: nil) else { return }
    let happy_alt = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at:url, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: [])
    print("happy_alt : ", happy_alt)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

**Notice how you should structure your folders in project navigator**

[image]